# How do I convert from date to character string in a sas macro

Tags: sas

This is part of a larger query, used to create a table that contains observations within a month, and using that month as the table name. 
I'd like the table name to be a sensible looking date, not a numeric.

Why does this %sysfunc(putc()) function not create a character string?

```
%macro transLiteralDate2Char(dateval=);  
%put numerical = &dateval.;  
%put sasdatavalue = %sysfunc(putc(&dateval,MONYY5.));
%mend;
%transLiteralDate2Char(dateval=%sysfunc(mdy(3,1,2016)));
```

Comment: Try putn instead of putc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `put` command in SAS always returns a character string. The distinction between `%sysfunc(putc())` and `%sysfunc(putn())` is what type of format the second argument of the function is - `putc` understands character formats and `putn` understands numeric formats. In this case, because date formats are numeric, you want to use `%sysfunc(putn())` to print your string. Like this:

```
%macro transLiteralDate2Char(dateval=);  
  %put sasdatavalue = %sysfunc(putn(&dateval,MONYY5.));
%mend;
%transLiteralDate2Char(dateval=%sysfunc(mdy(3,1,2016)));
```

Check out the examples [here](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sclref&docsetTarget=p1li9po7f9dg1fn1o1jk1hxo63og.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the second parameter in %SYSFUNC()

```
%put %sysfunc(today(), date9.);
```